# Como lincar categorias de um post em um site WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Tenho um site em *WordPress*. Quero exibir as categorias no *post*, ou seja, no meu tema. Tentei o código abaixo, mas só aparece o nome das categorias da postagem, mas somente texto, não tem como clicar e ir na categoria.. Podem me ajudar ?

**Meu Codigo:**

```
<div>
<?php 
    foreach((get_the_category()) as $category){
        echo $category->name."<br>";
        echo category_description($category);
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acontece que você não está criando o elemento *anchor* (ou `<a>`).

O correto é:

```
<div>
<?php 
    foreach(get_the_category() as $category){
        echo "<a href=\"".get_category_link($category->term_id)."\">{$category->name}</a><br>";
        echo category_description($category);
    }
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Ótimo, me ajudou bastante!